# Why do I get warnings in jupyter notebook for python 3.6 and how do I fix them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run the below code and I have been see a lot of these warning, I just want to know how can stop them from happening, what is it that is exactly causing these warning,

Why do I get the following warnings when I run the below code,

```
# Test options and evaluation metric
seed = 7
scoring = 'accuracy'

results = []
names = []

# evaluate each model in turn
for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(
        model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

WARNINGS:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py:432: FutureWarning: Default solver will be changed to 'lbfgs' in 0.22. Specify a solver to silence this warning.
  FutureWarning)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py:459: FutureWarning: Default multi_class will be changed to 'auto' in 0.22. Specify the multi_class option to silence this warning.
  "this warning.", FutureWarning)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py:432: FutureWarning: Default solver will be changed to 'lbfgs' in 0.22. Specify a solver to silence this warning.
  FutureWarning)
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well.
It warns about syntax change in upcoming python versions that you have written in your code.
Possibly if you run the same code in future versions may not work as intended.

Comment: how do I upgrade my python version in jupyter notebook, which python 3.6.5 to python 3.7? I have upgraded it on the terminal but on jupyter notebook it still shows as 3.6.5

Comment: If you are using anaconda distribution, [this](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html) might be helpful.